# sql select statement as bind variable for dynamic plsql block

Tags: variables, plsql, bind, execute-immediate

I am trying to run plsql anonymous block using execute immediate and the plsql block contains a bind variable for which the value is a sql select statement. But it seems this does not work. Is there any solution for to solve this.
 E.g.

```
BEGIN
  V_SQL:='SELECT emp_id FROM  emp  WHERE  dept_id=10;
  PLSQL_BLOCK:='DECLARE
    type emp_type
    IS
    TABLE OF NUMBER;
    emp_id emp_type;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :1 BULK COLLECT INTO emp_id;  
    END';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PLSQL_BLOCK USING V_SQL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you need to run an entire dynamic PLSQL block by using as SQL query as a bind variable; if so, you can try this way:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vPlSqlBlock varchar2(10000);
  3      vSQL        varchar2(1000);
  4  BEGIN
  5    vSQL:='SELECT 1 from dual';
  6    --
  7    vPlSqlBlock:='DECLARE
  8      type emp_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  9      emp_id   emp_type;
 10      vSQLDyn  varchar2(1000) := :1;
 11      BEGIN
 12          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQLDyn BULK COLLECT INTO emp_id;
 13          --
 14          /* whatever you need to do in your block */
 15          for i in emp_id.first .. emp_id.last loop
 16              dbms_output.put_line(emp_id(i));
 17          end loop;
 18      END;';
 19
 20      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vPlSqlBlock USING vSQL;
 21  end;
 22  /
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> declare
  2      vPlSqlBlock varchar2(10000);
  3      vSQL        varchar2(1000);
  4  BEGIN
  5    vSQL:='SELECT 1 from dual';
  6    --
  7    vPlSqlBlock:='DECLARE
  8      type emp_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  9      emp_id   emp_type;
 10      vSQLDyn  varchar2(1000) := :1;
 11      BEGIN
 12          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vSQLDyn BULK COLLECT INTO emp_id;
 13          /* this does nothing */
 14      END;';
 15
 16      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vPlSqlBlock USING vSQL;
 17  end;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried running without loop but it throws this error :PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: What do you mean without loop? Maybe you removed too much? Just edited to show how this can work with or without the loop; of course the version without loop does nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this.Hope this helps.

```
    set serveroutput on;
    set define on;
    DECLARE
  V_SQL varchar2(1000):='SELECT emp_id from emp where deptno = 10';
  PLSQL_BLOCK varchar2(1000):='DECLARE    
                                type emp_type    
                                IS    
                                TABLE OF NUMBER;    
                                emp_id emp_type;   
                                BEGIN        
                                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :1 BULK COLLECT INTO emp_id;      
                                END;';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PLSQL_BLOCK USING V_SQL;
END;
```

Comment: my bind variable is a select query

Comment: Modified the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: This code gets compiled successfully but while running it gives error         PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Also I am trying to run this entire block using execute immediate

Answer (score 0):

You have to first declare the variables you want to use in your execution block.

Try this:

```
DECLARE
    V_SQL VARCHAR2(1000) := 'SELECT emp_id FROM  emp  WHERE  dept_id=10';
    PLSQL_BLOCK varchar2(1000) :='DECLARE type emp_type IS TABLE OF integer; emp_id emp_type;'
        || ' BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :1 BULK COLLECT INTO emp_id; END;';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PLSQL_BLOCK USING V_SQL;
END;
/
```

Comment: concatenating the sql query to the plsql block also gives error. I tried this way.